# Android: Dagger hilt, inject navigation component

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger, dagger-hilt

I am trying to provide my navController with dagger hilt. But the approach I am using does not work.
I want to provide the navController in order to Inject it in my fragment via constructor injection.

### Without Di.Module,  FragmentClass

```
private val navController by lazy { findNavController() }
private val appBarConf by lazy { AppBarConfiguration(navController.graph) }
```

### Current approach, Di.Module

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
object AndroidModule {

@Provides
fun provideNavController(@ApplicationContext context: Context): NavController = lazy {
    (context as AppCompatActivity).findNavController(R.navigation.nav_main)
}.value

@Provides
fun provideAppbarConfiguration(navController: NavController): AppBarConfiguration = lazy {
    AppBarConfiguration(navController.graph)
}.value
}
```

I've also created the FragmentFactory class in order to inject my dependency via the constructor. I know that `(context as AppCompatActivity)` is the problem here, but I don't know the proper solution..

I appreciate every help, thanks!

### Error

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.app.App cannot be cast to
> androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

Comment: You're casting the application context (of type `App`) to `AppCompatActivity`. Try changing the context qualifier, assuming you have another qualifier for activity context.

Comment: Nope, that does not work. I am getting `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ID does not reference a View inside this Activity`. I also had to change `InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)` to `InstallIn(ActivityComponent::class)`

Comment: @Andrew do you have `nav_main` in every single `Activity` that is marked with `@AndroidEntryPoint`?

Comment: Can you please try to get application context and check if it works?
`(context.applicationContext as AppCompatActivity).findNavController(R.navigation.nav_main)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works for me. The activity should be provided if you install in the `ActivityComponent`. I'm only injecting into navigators of a `Fragment`. So that's why I used `@InstallIn(ActivityComponent::class)`

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ActivityComponent::class)
object MainActivityModule {

    @Provides
    fun provideNavController(activity: Activity): NavController {
        return activity.findNavController(R.id.navHostFragment)
    }
}
```

The `R.id.navHostFragment` is in this case not the id of the navigation graph, but of the fragment host.

Edit: as Andrew pointed out. Don’t forget to annotate your fragment with `@AndroidEntryPoint`

Comment: This did work! But don't forget to @AndroidEntryPoint the fragment. Although I have to admit that there is no use case for me anymore. Thanks anyway!

Comment: After checking this again, I noticed this won't work for your `startDestination`, you will have to manually retrieve the `NavController` for your 'home' fragment.

Comment: To get the injection to work in the 'home' fragment, you can inject a Provider<NavController> instead of directly injecting the NavController